# MS Access: Object Required error

Tags: ms-access, runtime-error, ms-access-2010

This code is just meant to figure out a total and then a percentage of that total, and then display the percentage amount in a textbox. This code runs when a button on a form is clicked, but it uses data based in a subform on that form, and the textbox that it should display to is on the form. Both the form and the subform are invoked in the class list, so it confuses me as to why it comes up with an "Object Required" error.

```
Private Sub cmdTest_Click()
'Initialisation
Dim TotalAmount As Integer 
Dim GiftAid As Integer
'Processing
   If AllForms!frmGiftAid!subfrmqryGiftAid!PaymentIncrement Is Not Null Then
       If AllForms!frmGiftAid!subfrmqryGiftAid!PaymentIncrement = "Monthly" Then
          TotalAmount = _
            (AllForms!frmGiftAid!subfrmqryGiftAid!PaymentAmountPerIncrement * 12)
       Else
          TotalAmount = _
            AllForms!frmGiftAid!subfrmqryGiftAid!PaymentAmountPerIncrement
       End If
   End If

   'Termination
   GiftAid = (TotalAmount * 0.25)
   AllForms!frmGiftAid!subfrmqryGiftAid!subfrmqryGiftAidtxtGiftAid = GiftAid
End Sub
```

The line that the error occurs on is the first one that references the subform, so it's:

If AllForms!frmGiftAid!subfrmqryGiftAid!PaymentIncrement Is Not Null Then

I've tried using different variations of the code to reference the subform (just referencing the subform, using "Forms" instead of "AllForms") as well as trying it in the subform itself rather than the form and doing so on different events, such as On_Current() or On_Load(), but nothing has worked for me so far.

Any help that you could offer me would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reference the subform starting either with Me from the code module of the form, or Form, followed by the name of the form. You then have the name of the subform control, Form, to refer to the object contained, and finally and property of the contained form.

```
 Forms!frmGiftAid!subfrmqryGiftAid.Form!PaymentIncrement
```

Or

```
 Me.subfrmqryGiftAid.Form.PaymentIncrement
```

Note that it is important to use the name of the subform control, not the name of the form contained.

This code would run on the parent form and a record would need to be selected on the subform.

```
If Not IsNull(Me.subfrmqryGiftAid.Form.PaymentIncrement) Then
   If Me.subfrmqryGiftAid.Form.PaymentIncrement = "Monthly" Then
      TotalAmount = _
        Me.subfrmqryGiftAid.Form.PaymentAmountPerIncrement * 12)
   Else
      TotalAmount = _
        Me.subfrmqryGiftAid.Form.PaymentAmountPerIncrement
   End If
End If
```

Comment: The first one comes up with runtime error 2465 "Microsoft Access can't find the field "Form" referred to in your expression"

Comment: And the second one comes back with the same "Object Required" error

Comment: Where are you running your code? The parent form? The subform?

Comment: I'm running the code from the On_Click() event of the parent form.

Comment: You, Sir, are a genius. I do believe I owe you a pint.